# How to change default postgres user on django deployed on app engine standard environment?

Tags: django, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, djangoappengine

I have a project using django which is deployed in app engine standard environment.
When I use cloud_sql_proxy.exe for makemigrations on django, an error like this appears :

```
(venv) G:\John Drive\Python\Project\My Project>python manage.py makemigrations
G:\John Drive\Python\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

This is my settings.py

```
# [START gaestd_py_django_secret_config]
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
    # Use a local secret file, if provided

    env.read_env(env_file)
# [START_EXCLUDE]
elif os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    # Create local settings if running with CI, for unit testing

    placeholder = (
        f"SECRET_KEY=a\n"
        f"DATABASE_URL=sqlite://{os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')}"
    )
    env.read_env(io.StringIO(placeholder))
# [END_EXCLUDE]
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
    # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
    project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "django_settings")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
# [END gaestd_py_django_secret_config]

# Database
# [START db_setup]
# [START gaestd_py_django_database_config]
# Use django-environ to parse the connection string
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If the flag as been set, configure to use proxy
if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432

# [END gaestd_py_django_database_config]
# [END db_setup]

# Use a in-memory sqlite3 database when testing in CI systems
# TODO(glasnt) CHECK IF THIS IS REQUIRED because we're setting a val above
if os.getenv("TRAMPOLINE_CI", None):
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }
```

This is my .env file :

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://myproject:project123@//cloudsql/myproject-676524:asia-southeast1:myproject/myproject-db
GS_BUCKET_NAME=myproject-676524_myproject
SECRET_KEY=secret123
```

If you look at the config in the .env file I use the user `myproject` instead of the `postgres` user, while the error above says `password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

How to change the default `postgres` user to `myproject` user?

Comment: Are you sure that your server has been turned on? I got the same error sometime and I personally forgot to turn on the server.

Comment: Yes i have checked it on google cloud console and the server is running

Comment: @Aras121 any update?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks correct, I would suggest to try adding some `print` statements to the `settings.py`, so that you could see what is actually happening when the program runs, and to narrow down possible causes of the error. Some things you could check for:

- What data is actually present in `env`? I would check this both after you initialize it with `environ.Env(..)`, and after you read the `.env` file with `env.read_env(env_file)`.
- Which of their branches are executing? For example, is the `.env` file being found when you call `os.path.isfile(env_file)`? I would add a print statement to each of the `if` branches to check which ones are being run, and see if this matched your expectations.
- What data ends up in `DATABASES["default"]`? Again, I would check this twice, once after calling `env.db()`, and again after setting `HOST` and `PORT` if `USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY` is set.

Answer (score 0):

i ended deleting/recloning the repo and this error went away, no idea why, but poof no more error